# building android project produces make error 2

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, adt

I have recently purchased a book to assist in my development of C++ for Android which contained some code samples.  However, when I come to build some of the sample code, I receive the following error:

```
C:\ndk\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++  : Chapter10 <= Chapter10.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:/ndk/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/Chapter10/Chapter10.o.d -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Ijni -IC:/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/android/native_app_glue -IC:/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport -IC:/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -Ijni -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -frtti -c jni/Chapter10.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/Chapter10/Chapter10.o, ...) failed.

make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/Chapter10/Chapter10.o] Error 2
```

The make file is as shown below:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE          := arm
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE            := Chapter10
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := Chapter10.cpp \
                           (Other cpp Files . . . )
LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

The Application.mk file is as below:

```
APP_PLATFORM    := android-9
APP_STL         := stlport_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION   := 4.7
```

This was compiled using ADT v22.2.1 and Android NDK r9 on a Windows 7 Machine.

The NDK was installed to 'C:\ndk\android-ndk-r9\'.

Comment: What is the value of your ``NDK_HOME`` environment variable?

Comment: Sorry Sergey, but I am having trouble finding the location of the NDK_HOME Environment Variable.  I have set up the NDK Location Via Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> NDK Location to "C:\ndk\android-ndk-r9\". This appears to be found during the build.  I forgot that I am running Windows 7 (Edit main post).

Comment: And your ``Application.mk``, please.

Comment: The Application.mk has now been supplied in the main post.

Comment: Could you, please, try to compile sample code "hello-jni" under the NDK r9 folder. Does if work?

Comment: The hello-jni project compiled and was successfully delivered to an Android Device.  hello-gl2 as well.  Imported both projects into ADT using the same build and deploy process, just this project does not build correctly.

Comment: Does it use the same ``NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION``?

Comment: The sample above uses NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION 4.7.  The hello-jni sample does not contain an Application.mk.  So here's what I did.  I removed the line for NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION in Application.mk, and the project compiled fine.  Your suggestion has certainly led to the solution, but the ultimate question is why?

Comment: I summarized it in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android NDK r9 contains the following toolchains:

1. arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
2. arm-linux-androideabi-4.8
3. arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.2
4. arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.3
5. llvm-3.2
6. llvm-3.3
7. mipsel-linux-android-4.6
8. mipsel-linux-android-4.8
9. mipsel-linux-android-clang3.2
10. mipsel-linux-android-clang3.3
11. x86-4.6
12. x86-4.8
13. x86-clang3.2
14. x86-clang3.3

**There is no toolchain for gcc 4.7.** However, your `Application.mk` contains the line:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION   := 4.7
```

Which tells the NDK to look for the 4.7 toolchain. And it fails.

So, the solution to your problem is changing the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` variable to `4.6`, `4.8`, `clang3.2`, `clang3.3`, or just `clang` (which will use the most recent version of Clang available in the NDK).

Answer (score 0):

Check your project path if is contain **spaces** and **non-english characters**.
I moved my project into somewhere without spaces, re-build it and works.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny, but this issue was clearly resolved with the process outlined by Sergey's Solution.