# Apportable load the tweejump-master makes errors

Tags: apportable

I try to use apportable to load the demo to my android phone.but have errors.

```
 localhost:tweejump-master zhangxueyuan$ apportable load
```

Building with `TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False`

Building to `/Users/zhangxueyuan/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug`

```
Warning: Falling back to toolchain version 4.7. Please run 'apportable update_toolchain'
Error: Could not find file /Users/zhangxueyuan/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin
```

and

```
localhost:tweejump-master zhangxueyuan$ apportable build
```

Building with `TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False`

Building to `/Users/zhangxueyuan/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug`

```
Warning: Falling back to toolchain version 4.7. Please run 'apportable update_toolchain'
Error: Could not find file /Users/zhangxueyuan/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin
```

I refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477500/building-android-project-produces-make-error-2/19492012#19492012),and I think if the apportable will create a file to compile the project .

I think maybe change one file in the Folder：`~/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/。`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok，i have find the answer。

i change the file /Users/zhangxueyuan/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/ndk.py

the number 303 to env['NDK_VERSION'] = '4.8'.

then
i apportable build the project again.

the result have errors:  Could not find file /Users/zhangxueyuan/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin

i find the only have the drawin-x86-64.
so i copy them by myself
use  cp -R darwin-x86_64/ darwin-x86/

and try build project again.

apportable run ok!